# How to solve "[: too many arguments" error, when testing result of division?

Tags: linux, shell

```
isDivisible(){
    if [  $number / 2 -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "$number is divisible by 2 because the remainder of $number/2 is 0"
    fi
}
```

```
./myscript.sh: line 2: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: The only syntax the `[` command accepts is that documented in `man test`, as `[` and `test` are two names for the same command (which differs when called under the `[` name only insofar as it fails unless its last argument is `]`). `/` is not part of that syntax, and neither is `%` (which is what you'd actually need to use in this case).

Comment: ...so, `[ "$((number % 2))" -eq 0 ]` would also work, albeit much more kludgily than what the given answer suggests. (You can't use `/` to calculate a remainder without additional operations; only `%` does that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Your alternative would require something like bash or zsh. Maybe a better alternative would be to sue `bc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash:

- For arithmetic use `((...))`. Side benefit, it lets you use the more natural `==` operator, and variables in an arithmetic context don't need dollar signs.
- Use modulus not division.

```
#!/bin/bash

isDivisible() {
    if ((number % 2 == 0)); then
       echo "$number is divisible by 2 because the remainder of $number/2 is 0"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not work in general Posix shell, as required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The `[` command does not perform general expression evaluation.  Rather, it evaluates only expressions of a handful specific, idiosyncratic forms described in [its documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).  The `-eq` operator is among those supported, but the `/` is not, and `[` in any case does not itself handle subexpressions.

But any POSIX-conforming shell can evaluate arithmetic expressions via arithmetic expansion, which you get by enclosing the expression to be evaluated between `$((` and `))`.  At this point, however, it is important to note that this will get you *integer* arithmetic, not floating-point arithmetic, and that either way, *x* / 2 == 0 is not an appropriate test for determining whether *x* is even.  As @JohnKugelman pointed out in his answer, you want `%`, the modulus operator, not `/`.

Overall, then:

```
isDivisibleBy2() {
    if [ $(( $number % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "$number is divisible by 2 because the remainder of $number/2 is 0"
    fi
}
```